# SETX not setting system variable when using /M

Tags: setx

I am trying to set a persistent system variable. This is for a process in which a batch file refers to the variable, and then edits the variable at the end of the process.

I am using `setx` with the `/M` parameter, however, it continues to create the environment variable under the local user instead of the system.

The command I am specifically running is:

```
setx FN 101 /M
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not launch an elevated CMD. Turns out in order for the /M parameter to work, CMD must be run as an administrator.